# Преобразование строки в математическое выражение

Tags: javascript, replace

Стоит задача преобразовать полученную на вход строку, которая является математическим выражением, в реальное математическое выражение и посчитать его результат на java script. `eval()` использовать нельзя.

Учитывая это я решил воспользоваться операцией замены строк, где беру два операнда и оператор между ними и произвожу математическую операцию. Все операции должны производиться, как в реальной математике: у скобок наивысший приоритет, операции в порядке * / + - и слева направо.

Проблема состоит в том, что я произвёл `split` выражения по скобкам, передаю в функцию математический оператор и кусок строки с математическим выражением, пропускаю данный кусок через `replace` и в функции пытаюсь отловить регуляркой мой переданный математический оператор и его операнды и произвести соответствующую математическую операцию и вернуть вместо выражения его результат.

Суть алгоритма в том, чтобы пропустить участок исходной строки через 4 оператора и по итогу вернуть число. Такую же операцию произвести со всеми участками. Сама проблема в том, что не происходит `replace` строк и выражение возвращается без изменений.

```
+(function(){
    var inputString = prompt("Enter a math expression here", "0");
    var arrayOfMathSymbols = ['*', '/', '+', '-'];

    //checking block of math expression
    var splitExpression = inputString.split('');
    var testArray = splitExpression.filter( function(item){
        if(!isNaN(+item)) return item;
        else if( /[\*\/\+\-\(\)]/g.test(item) ) return item;        
    });    
    if (testArray.length != splitExpression.length) {
        alert("Please enter a correct math expressions contains numbers or * / + - ( )");
        throw("Lexical error in the expression");
    }  
    // end of the cheking block

    var arrayAfterSplitOnBracket = inputString.split(/[\(\)]/g);

    while(true) {
        if(arrayAfterSplitOnBracket.length > 1){
            for(let i = parseInt((arrayAfterSplitOnBracket / 2) - 1); i > 0;) {
                arrayOfMathSymbols.forEach( function(item, i, arr) {

                       var resultCalculation = Calculate(item,arrayAfterSplitOnBracket[i]);
                       arrayAfterSplitOnBracket[i] = resultCalculation;                    
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            arrayOfMathSymbols.forEach( function(item, i, arr) {

                var resultCalculation = Calculate(item,arrayAfterSplitOnBracket[0]);
                arrayAfterSplitOnBracket[0] = resultCalculation;

            });
        }
        break;
    }

    //Define block of functions
    function Calculate(mathSymbol, partOfMathExpression) {
        let regularNote = new RegExp('[\\+\\-]?\\d+\\' + mathSymbol + '[\\+\\-]?\\d+', 'gi');
        partOfMathExpression.replace(regularNote, function(str, offset, s) {
            let afterSplit = str.split(mathSymbol);
            switch(mathSymbol) {
                case '*': return afterSplit[0] * afterSplit[1];
                    break;
                case '/': return afterSplit[0] / afterSplit[1];
                    break;
                case '+': return (parseInt(afterSplit[0]) + parseInt(afterSplit[1]));
                    break;
                case '-': return afterSplit[0] - afterSplit[1];
                    break;
            }
        });
        return partOfMathExpression; //для примера 1*2 после первого прохода здесь должно получится 2, но на выходе всё тоже выражение 1*2
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Преобразовать строку в математическое выражение js и получить его результат можно так (получается калькулятор на js):

```js
const exp = document.getElementById('exp');
const calcButton = document.getElementById('calc');
const calcResult = document.getElementById('result');

calcButton.addEventListener('click', calcFunc);

const actions = {
  multiplication: {
    value: '*',
    label: 'multiplication',
    func: (a,b) => (parseInt(a) * parseInt(b))
  },
  division: {
    value: '/',
    label: 'division',
    func: (a,b) => (a / b)
  },
  addition: {
    value: '+',
    label: 'addintion',
    func: (a,b) => (parseInt(a) + parseInt(b))
  },
  subtraction: {
    value: '-',
    label: 'subtraction',
    func: (a,b) => (parseInt(a) - parseInt(b))
  }
}

function calcFunc() {
  const res = parseBrackets(exp.value);
  calcResult.innerHTML = res;
}

function parseBrackets(str) {
  const out = str.match(/\((.*)\)/);
  if (out) {
    const expResult = parseBrackets(out[1]);
    str = str.replace(out[0], expResult);
    return calcExpr(str);
  } else {
    return calcExpr(str);
  }
}

function calcExpr(str) {
  let res;
  Object.keys(actions).map(function(type) {
    res = parseExpr(str, actions[type]);
    if (res) {
      str = str.replace(res.str, res.value.toString());
      str = calcExpr(str);
    }
  });
  return str;
}
 
function parseExpr(str, action) {
  const reg = new RegExp(`((\\d+)\\s*\\${action.value}\\s*(\\d+))`);
  const out = str.match(reg);
  if (!out) return false;
  
  const result = {
    str: out[1]
  };
  
  result.value = action.func(out[2], out[3]);
  return result;
}
```

```html
<input id="exp" type="text">
    <button id="calc">Calculate</button>
    
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`String.replace` не меняет строку, от которой вызывается, а возвращает новую, измененную строку.

```
partOfMathExpression = partOfMathExpression.replace(...);
```